# Error when in maintenance mode

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

when i put my basic drupal 7 website in maintenance mode, it shows an error.

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /www/public_html/includes/theme.inc on line 2440
```

I have not changed the theme.inc file, and I do not get this error when the site isn't in maintenance mode. As the error states, one of the array elements appears to be an object while a string is expected.

Any ideas for debugging?

Comment: Did you make any modifications to the standard Garland/Bartik themes? And also what do you have on line 2440 of theme.inc (what line of which function is there)? because I have a closing bracket on all my 7.12 sites.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using omega check if you have a custom region called "user". It seems maintenance mode adds "user" object to variables array and if you have a "user" region doesn't work properly.

Remove or rename the "user" region and it should work again.
Check [tauno](https://www.drupal.org/u/tauno) comment #1  for more information: https://www.drupal.org/node/1936480#comment-7268482

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to `var_dump` the objects you find on that line (2440). You might need an `exit;` after that to make sure you can see the output. Once you find out which object is the wrong type (i.e. the stdClass should be a string or vice versa), you can trace upwards and find where it was set.

If you can tell us the precise Drupal version you're using or paste the whole function block, we might be able to narrow down the problem too.